# Firestore query list of documents with sort order and pagination

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a feed where a user can follow projects, and those projects will show up in the user's feed, sorted by a `lastUpdated` field, and allow for pagination, but I can't figure out what the best approach is.

The basic Firestore structure looks like:

```
users (collection)
  projects (subcollection)
    lastUpdated (timestamp)
  followingProjects (array of project Document IDs)
```

I could use an `in` operator like:

```
let followingProjects = user.followingProjects
firestore().collectionGroup("projects")
           .whereField(FieldPath.documentID(), in: followingProjects)
           .order(by: "lastUpdated", descending: true)
           .limit(to: 20)
           // And later for pagination :
           .start(afterDocument: startAfter)
```

But I believe the `in` operator is [limited to 30 values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en&authuser=0#limits_on_or_queries) in `followingProjects`, and I would like to allow following more than 30 projects.

A solution I can think of is to create a separate subcollection for followingProjects, so the new structure would be:

```
users (collection)
  projects (subcollection)
    lastUpdated (timestamp)
  followingProjects (subcollection)
    id (string)
    lastUpdated (timestamp)
```

In this case, to get the feed, I'd run a collectionGroup query to get the latest followingProjects so I can sort and paginate, followed by individual `getDocument()` queries for each project. Every time a project is updated, it would have to update the `lastUpdated` for each user that's following the project though, and this seems inefficient.

Is there a better approach I'm missing?

Comment: You also can't use `FieldPath.documentID()` as a filter in a collection group query. You can only filter on document fields, and the document ID isn't considered one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188250/how-to-perform-collection-group-query-using-document-id-in-cloud-firestore

Comment: @DougStevenson Oh thanks for the clarification, I was wondering about that!

Comment: "this seems inefficient" What is inefficient about it? What would you consider efficient for that?

Comment: It seems inefficient in terms of the number of write operations to support paginating the most recently updated Projects. If a project has 1000 followers, any update to the project would require 1000 writes, one for each follower, to update its lastUpdated field (the lastUpdated field need to be updated so the followingProjects collectionGroup query can be ordered and paginated).

The end goal is for the user to have a pagination-enabled feed that shows the most recently updated Projects that they're following, with no limit on how many Projects they can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I needed in another answer!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58100387/482536

Instead of storing Project IDs in a `followingProjects` array as part of the User, the Project should store User IDs in a `followers` array. Then I can run the following query without worrying about the disjunctions limit, and there are no separate documents to keep updated whenever a Project is updated.

```
let userID = user.id
firestore().collectionGroup("projects")
       .whereField("followers", arrayContains: userID)
       .order(by: "lastUpdated", descending: true)
       .limit(to: 20)
       // And later for pagination :
       .start(afterDocument: startAfter)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a collection group index, the `__name__` field (which is what `FieldPath.documentID()` maps to) is populated with the **path** of the document, rather than just its document ID. So if you want to filter on `FieldPath.documentID()`, you will need to know the entire path of the document(s).

Alternatively, you can add a regular field with the document ID to each document, and filter on that in your collection group query.

Comment: That would work, then I can do whereField("documentID", in: followingProjects)! But my main issue is that [according to this limit on disjunctions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en&authuser=0#limits_on_or_queries), it would be limited to 30 entries in followingProjects. 

I could feed in 30 projects at a time, but then I can't use the sort order or pagination. I'm hoping to support possibly hundreds of projects to follow.

Comment: If you want to get more than 30 values, you'll have to use multiple queries. But that is unrelated to using a single top-level collection or multiple subcollections.

Comment: I think the OP was asking specifically how to avoid having to get the individual documents *after* the collection group query.  The fact that they were using an invalid filter on the query was incidental (hence my comment).  The primary solution here is (of course and unfortunately) to copy all the other document data into the documents that participated in the collection group query.

Comment: Right! The added reads to the individual documents and syncing all of the user's followingProjects lastUpdated timestamp when a Project is updated. So if a Project has 10 followers, then writing to a Project now has to write to 10 other documents in every user's followingProjects subcollection. I'm open to reorganizing the collection hierarchy, if it helps, but I just can't think of how it would help. Thank you!